# Slow down time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

To debug some issues in my code, I need to slow down some animations, and therefore I was about to write a simple JavaScript code that would slow down the time, so I don't have to rewrite the entire code for such a temporary purpose.

My code is:

```
(function() {
  var ___speed = 0.20; // <-- 20%, i.e. 5 times slower
  var ___date = Date.now();
  var ___now = Date.now; // <-- Reference to original method/function
  Date.prototype.now = function() {
    return ___date + Math.floor((___now() - ___date) * ___speed);
  };
})();
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but it doesn't work, as the system doesn't use my new method `now()` at all.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8son349h/).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to intercept calls to the `Date` object and execute our own code.

> The Proxy object enables you to create a proxy for another object, which can intercept and redefine fundamental operations for that object.

We can also add a `prototype` to capture `toString` as it isn't captured in the proxies `get` handler.

```js
let ___speed = 0.20; // <-- 20%, i.e. 5 times slower
let ___date = Date.now();
let ___now = Date.now; // <-- Reference to original method/function

console.log('Before Proxy Tests')
console.log('Test #1')
console.log(Date(Date.now()))
console.log(new Date(Date.now()).toString())
console.log(Date())

Date = new Proxy(Date, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    if (prop === 'now') {
      let date = new Date()
      date.now = () => this.calculate()
      // Returns our version of date.now
      return Reflect.get(date, prop, receiver)
    }
    // Returns the Date's version of the captured property (original)
    return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver)
  },
  apply(target, thisArg, argumentList) {
    // Returns a date in ISO format. when `Date()` is called  
    let date = new Date(this.calculate())
    // "argumentList[0]" may also be the value passed to `Date()`, such as "1611609409038"
    if (argumentList[0] === 'toISOString') {
        return date.toISOString()
    }
    return date.toString()
  },
  calculate() {
    // Our calculations
    return ___date + Math.floor((___now() - ___date) * ___speed)
  }
})

console.log('After Proxy Tests')
console.log('Test #2')
console.log(Date(Date.now()))
console.log(new Date(Date.now()).toString())
console.log(Date())

// Handle toString calls on the Proxy date object
Date.prototype.toString = () => Date.call(Date, 'toISOString')

console.log('Test #3')
console.log(Date(Date.now()))
console.log(new Date(Date.now()).toString())
console.log(Date())
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log('Button Click [1]:', Date(Date.now()));">Date(Date.now()</button>&nbsp;
<button onclick="console.log('Button Click [2]:', new Date(Date.now()).toString());">new Date(Date.now()).toString()</button>&nbsp;
<button onclick="console.log('Button Click [3]:', Date());">Date()</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Date.now` is not an instance method, it's static. Have you tried

```
Date.now = function() {
    return ___date + Math.floor((___now() - ___date) * ___speed);
  };
```