# Slow down world time and rendering in Javascript for Webkit / Chrome

Tags: javascript, webkit

I would like to record browser animations in the smoothest possible framerate, including an alpha channel. Due to single threaded performance limitations I am looking for a way to slow down the producer of these animations. I currently achieve this by increasing the delay and duration of timers (in my case anime.js), this allows me to sample screen at a lower frame rate, while the target frame rate can be achieved.

The change of duration and delays is not overly painful, but I would like to do this in a more generic way. For example instruct the browser to have a world clock that runs on 10% of real speed. I have already found the Proxy suggestion below, but this does not seem to impact the current animation rendering.
[Slow down time with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65888075/slow-down-time-with-javascript)

What can be done to globally reduce all the animation, as if everything would take 10 times longer?